# Java Generic For Parameterized Class : Unbounded Wildcards vs Raw Type

Tags: java, generics, raw-types, unbounded-wildcard, parameterized-class

I have a parameterized interface RestHandler.

```
public interface RestHandler<T> {
   blah blah blah...
}
```

And I need to create a class from config using Class.forName. Now I come up with three version , which ALL compiles successfully.

Version 1:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> RestHandler<T> create(final String handlerImplFqcn) throws ClassNotFoundException, 
                                                                    IllegalAccessException, 
                                                                    InstantiationException {
    Class<?> handlerClass = Class.forName(handlerImplFqcn);
    return (RestHandler<T>) handlerClass.newInstance();
}
```

Version 2:

```
public static RestHandler<?> create(final String handlerImplFqcn) throws ClassNotFoundException, 
                                                                    IllegalAccessException, 
                                                                    InstantiationException {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class handlerClass = Class.forName(handlerImplFqcn);
    return (RestHandler<?>) handlerClass.newInstance();
}
```

Version 3:

```
public static RestHandler<?> create(final String handlerImplFqcn) throws ClassNotFoundException, 
                                                                    IllegalAccessException, 
                                                                    InstantiationException {
    Class<?> handlerClass = Class.forName(handlerImplFqcn);
    return (RestHandler<?>) handlerClass.newInstance();
}
```

My question is , why they ALL work and which one would be best practice ?

Comment: My personal preference is for the first example, though you shouldn't need the SuppressWarnings Annotation. Though you should note that it's possible to also throw ClassCastException in all of these examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1, re-written to this:

```
public static <T extends RestHandler<?>> RestHandler<T> create(final String handlerImplFqcn) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, ClassCastException {
    Class<T> handlerClass = (Class<T>) Class.forName(handlerImplFqcn);
    return (RestHandler<T>) handlerClass.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean
    

`public static <T extends RestHander<?>> T create(String handlerImplFqcn) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<T> handlerClass = (Class<T>) Class.forName(handlerImplFqcn);
        return handlerClass.newInstance();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Use version 1.

Version 2 uses raw types - avoid these if at all possible.

Version 3 uses `<?>` which is also often an anti pattern as it rarely achieves what you mean to achieve.